# TortoiseGIT TRUNK Clone issue

Tags: github, tortoisegit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf2Uv.png)I am trying to clone the Trunk from SVN repository through tortoisegit tool I am getting only dump file(check image file) instead of Trunk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to clone tunk data of SVN repo through  gitbash  so could you please provide me the commands to clone

Comment: when i am trying to clone the trunk of my SVN repo through tortoisegit tool , it is cloning perl.exe.stackdump file instead of my trunk

Comment: please suggest how can I clone my trunk from SVN repository through tortoisegit tool